# Working out the coefficient of a polynomial function

Tags: calculus

The following information is about function $g$ which is defined for all real numbers $x\neq 1 $

$(i.)$ $g=\frac{p}{q}$ where $p(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ and $q(x) = dx + e$ for some constants $a, b, c, d, e;$

$(ii).$ The only x-intercept of the curve $y = g(x)$ occurs at the origin;

$(iii).$ $g(x)\geq 0$ on the interval $[ ~0, 1)$ and is negative elsewhere on its domain;

$(iv).$ $g$ has a vertical asymptote at $x = 1$; and

$(v).$ $\ g(\frac{1}{2}) = 3$.

**Write an explicit formula for $g$ by determining the constants $a....e$.**

**Attempt**

$b=0 ~;~ c=0$ can be deduced by the intercept at the origin.

Denominator is $d(x-1)$ by noticing the vertical asymptote at $x=1$.

$a<0$ by noticing the concavity at $[~0,1)$.

$\frac{1}{4}a+\frac{1}{2}b=-\frac{3}{2}d$ can be evaluted by $g(\frac{1}{2})=3$

However, I cannot piece the rest. Can somebody please help?

Comment: Hint: Since the only $x$-intercept is at the origin both $c$ _and_ $b$ are zero.

Comment: @DMcMor Oh yes, If b wasn't equal to zero, there would be more x-intercepts.

Comment: Ok, follow up hint: At this point you can write your function as $g(x) = \frac{ax}{d(x-1)}$.  Pick a value for $d$, maybe $d=1$ for convenience, and  then use $g(1/2) = 3$ to solve for $a$.  There is not a unique solution for $a$ and $d$.

Comment: Hint: note that $4/2 = 2/1 = 6/3 = \dots$

Comment: Wait. Shouldn't it be $\frac{ax^2}{d(x-1)}$?

Comment: Ah, yes, oops.  Actually we should take $a = 0$ otherwise we'll lose the requirement that $g$ changes sign at $x = 0$, so really it should be $g(x) = \frac{bx}{d(x-1)}$

Comment: Can you please elaborate the supposition again? @DMcMor?

Comment: Yes, sorry I shouldn't try to multitask.  Since we know that the only $x$-intercept is at $x = 0$ we know that either the numerator is $ax^{2}$ or $bx$.  Because we know that $g(x) \geq 0$ on $[0,1)$ and negative elsewhere, that is it changes sign at $x = 0$, we know that it can't be $ax^{2}$ because that doesn't change signs at the origin.

Comment: @DMcMor Apologies for questioning even after you explained it very simply but can you also answer why $ax^2$ doesn't changes sign at origin considering the presence of denominator? In my opinion it should be $ax^2$ since for $x<0$ the function $g = \frac{+}{-} = - <0 $ but if $bx$ then $g= \frac{-}{-} = +>0$ nullifying the condition stating $g$ is negative for $x<0$

Comment: $x^{2}$ is always positive and $x - 1$ is positive for $x > 1$ and negative for $x < 1$.  That means that $\frac{x^{2}}{x-1}$ is negative for $x<1$ and positive for $x > 1$, meaning that a function of the form $\frac{ax^{2}}{d(x-1)}$ can't change sign at $x = 0$.  On the other hand, $x$ is negative for $x<0$ and positive for $x>0$ so $\frac{bx}{d(x-1)}$ will be change sign at the origin.  You just need to choose values of $b$ and $d$ so the signs are correct.

Comment: Ohh perfect thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

"c= 0 can be deduced by the intercept at the origin.
Denominator is d(x−1) by noticing the vertical asymptote at x=1."

The fact that x= 0 is **only** x intercept is important!

Yes, so the function is of the form $g(x)= \frac{ax^2+ bx}{d(x- 1)}= \frac{x(ax+ b)}{d(x- 1)}$  Notice that if ax+ b= 0 for x other than 1, x= -b/a would also be a zero.  Since the **only** x intercept is x= 0, ax+ b must be ax- a= a(x- 1).  In that case we have $g(x)= \frac{ax(x- 1)}{d(x- 1)}$ which, for any x other than 1, is equal to $\frac{a}{d}x$.  Since g(1/2)= 3, we must have $\left(\frac{a}{d}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)= 3$ so that $\frac{a}{d}= 6$.  That means that $g(x)= 6x$ for $x\ne 1$, g(1) is undefined.

Comment: But $g(x)=6x$ doesn't have a vertical asymptote at $x=1$ which is the fourth condition.

Comment: And I did not say that the answer **was** "g(x)= 6x"!

Comment: I didn't even said that was the answer. All i told you the statement $g(x)=6x$ is wrong whether it is an assumption or conclusion since it doesn't adhere to rule 4.